# Python adding the values

Tags: python

```
# Initialising list of dictionary
ini_dict = [{'a':5, 'b':10, 'c':90},
         {'a':45, 'b':78},
         {'a':90, 'c':10}]

# printing initial dictionary
print ("initial dictionary", (ini_dict))

# sum the values with same keys
result = {}
for d in ini_dict:
   for k in d.keys():
      result[k] = result.get(k,0) + d[k]


print("resultant dictionary : ", (result))
```

Can someone explain the program line by line

Comment: Is there any specific part you don't understand? Have you tried searching specific statements one by one to get their meaning?

Answer (score 2):

Creating a list of dictionary's

```
ini_dict = [{'a':5, 'b':10, 'c':90},
     {'a':45, 'b':78},
     {'a':90, 'c':10}]
```

Prints out the list with dictionary's

```
print ("initial dictionary", (ini_dict))
```

Creates a new dictionary

```
result = {}
```

Loop's through the List of dictionarys

```
 for d in ini_dict:
```

so the first `d` would be `{'a':5, 'b':10, 'c':90}`

Loop's through the keys of that dict

```
for k in d.keys():
```

-> a, b and c

Creates or gets the same key in the result dict and adds the value from the current key. Default value for a new created key is 0.

```
result[k] = result.get(k,0) + d[k]
```

Prints out the `result` dict

```
print("resultant dictionary : ", (result))
```

Answer (score 0):

the first line initialises a list of three dictionaries.

```
ini_dict = [{'a':5,  'b':10, 'c':90},
            {'a':45, 'b':78},
            {'a':90,         'c':10}]
```

next up, the dictionary is printed

```
print ("initial dictionary", (ini_dict))
```

finally, a weighted histogram is made of the dictionaries based on the keys of the elements within said dictionaries. This is done in three steps:

1. iterating over the list of dictionaries to get at each different dictionary.

```
for d in ini_dict:
```

remember: `ini_dict` is a list of dictionaries. when you for-loop over a list, the symbol (here `d`) becomes each of the dictionaries.

2. iterating over the keys in the dictionary. The method `dict.keys()` returns a list of keys, over which can be iterated.

```
for k in d.keys():
```

3. finally, for each key in the dictionary the corresponding key in the result dictionary is modified to add the new value. with `result.get(k,0)` the value for the key k in the result dictionary is fetched, but `0` is the default value if the key is not present.

```
result[k] = result.get(k,0) + d[k]
```

This just replaces the result with the previous result + the value in d.

At the end of this bit of code, the result dictionary has the added value of each of the keys.